# Spring Framework RESTful services

Tags: mysql, spring, rest, mybatis

I am building my first Spring RESTful API on Eclipse. I am not able to call the APIs. I get the, "The requested resource is not available." error when I use http://localhost:8080/InterVUEService/api/Clinic/7.

**WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>InterVUEService</display-name>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- SERVLET DEFINITIONS -->
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/InterVUEService/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

</web-app>
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

<!--Enable scanning of spring @Configuration classes -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- import core modules beans -->
<import resource="classpath:spring/application-context-core.xml" />
</beans>
```

**application-context-core.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- scan base package for components -->
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.abaxis.interVUEservice.*dao" />

<import resource="datasource-beans.xml" />



<!-- <task:annotation-driven /> -->

</beans>
```

**datasource-beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

<jee:jndi-lookup
        id="dataSource"
        jndi-name="jdbc/vetscanVueDS"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>  

        <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" >
    <qualifier value="mysqlDB"/>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txMysqlAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:mybatis/maps/*.xml"/>
<property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.abaxis.interVUEservice.model"/>
<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis/sqlmap-config.xml"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
<property name="basePackage" value="com.abaxis.interVUEservice.*dao"/>
</bean>                             
</beans>
```

**com.xxx.interVUEservice.api.impl**
ClinicResourceImpl.java

```
enter code here
package com.xxx.interVUEservice.api.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.xxx.interVUEservice.api.ClinicResource;
import com.xxx.interVUEservice.common.exception.BusinessException;
import com.xxx.interVUEservice.model.Clinic;
import com.xxx.interVUEservice.service.ClinicService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/Clinic/")
public class ClinicResourceImpl implements ClinicResource {


@Autowired
private ClinicService clinicService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)    
@ResponseBody
public List<Clinic> ClinicList() throws BusinessException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{clinicId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
@ResponseBody
public Clinic ClinicInfo(@PathVariable("clinicId") int id)  {

Clinic temp = new Clinic();

temp.setId(id);
temp.setName("ABC");
temp.setLicenseNumber("999999");
temp.setAddress("3240 XXX");
temp.setCity("XX");
temp.setState("XX");
temp.setPostcode("94599");
temp.setCountry("XXX");
temp.setPhoneNumber("0000-0000-0000");
temp.setActive(true);
temp.setLanguage("en");

return temp;
//Clinic clinic = clinicService.getClinic(id);

//return clinic;
}
```

}

**pom.xml**

```
enter code here
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi=  "http:        // www.w3.org/ 
2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation= "http://maven.apache.org /POM/4.0.0  http://    maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.abaxis</groupId>
<artifactId>InterVUEService</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>InterVUEService Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
<spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
<mybatis.version>3.2.3</mybatis.version>
<mybatis-spring.version>1.2.1</mybatis-spring.version>
<mysql.version>5.1.5</mysql.version>
<tomcat.version>7.0.72</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>        
</dependency>

<!-- Check if the following dependencies are required-->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
         <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
         <version>${mybatis-spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>${mybatis.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>InterVUEService</finalName>      
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
<contextFile>${basedir}/docs/context.xml
</contextFile>
</configuration>


<dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.5</version>
                        </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

Could you please tell me why I am not able to call http://localhost:8080/api/Clinic/id? Why is this Uri not working on my Tomcat server? Please help. I am a total newbie and learning to write Restful services for my next project at work to host on AWS.

Thanks
Nalini

Comment: Creating a minimum verifiable example will go a long way towards getting you an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Aaron. I got the answer marked.

Answer (score 1):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abaxis.interVUEservice.*dao"/>
```

can you try changing to

```
<context:component-scan  base-package="com.abaxis.interVUEservice" />
```

and use http://localhost:8080/InterVUEService/api/Clinic/7

Comment: Tried changing to com.abaxis.interVUEservice in application-context-core.xml. But same output. Requested resource is not available

Comment: <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>

Where is this file, looks like you named it wrongly. Also, I don't see mvc context file with <mvc:annotation-driven/>

Please add this and try.

Comment: I have spring-servlet.xml under WEB-INF folder under webapp folder. Where is the name wrong. I dont get what you meant. Also, I dont have a MVC context file since I dont have any web pages. This project is just for web api. Do I need one? Also, I have commented out <mvc:annotation-driven/> in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Murali for helping me resolve this issue. I changed the url-pattern in web.xml to `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` from `<url-pattern>/InterVUEService/*</url-pattern>` and I was able to call the API and get the json response. The issue was that when the url pattern was `/InterVUEService/*`, the uri was suppose to be http://localhost:8080/InterVUEService/InterVUEService/api/Clinic/7 and I was trying with http://localhost:8080/InterVUEService/api/Clinic/7.

Hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.